# Class Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have checked out, class `PermissionsTableSeeder` exists by path: `Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder`.

Also, I tried:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan cache:clear
```

When I run command: `php artisan db:seed` it gives me an exception:

> ReflectionException  : Class Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder
>   does not exist
>
> at
>   C:\Projects\secure_secure\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:790
>       786|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
>       787|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
>       788|         }
>       789|
>
> > 790|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
> >         791| 
> >         792|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
> >         793|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
> >         794|         // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1
>   ReflectionClass::__construct("Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder")
>         C:\Projects\secure_secure\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:790
>
> 2
>   Illuminate\Container\Container::build("Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder")
>         C:\Projects\secure_secure\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:667

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `Database\Seeds\` **namespace** in laravel, and seeders have no namespace by default.

Please check `DatabaseSeeder.php` you should have this function:

```
public function run()
{
    .....
    $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Check also that you have **not** given any **namespace** to the `DatabaseSeeder` class or to the `PermissionsTableSeeder` class.

You shoud remove also any line that start with `use Database\Seeds` in you `DatabaseSeeder.php` because that **namespace** does not exist.

Comment: I have this in DatabaseSeeder.php: ` $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);`

Comment: please check you have not a namespace directive in any of the two classes

Comment: In class `PermissionsTableSeeder` I have namespace: `use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;` and in class `Dataseeder`: `use Database\Seeds\ConnectRelationshipsSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;`

Comment: As I said above there is no `Database\Seeds` namespace plese comment out all rows that start with `use Database\Seeds` in your seeders.

Comment: @OPV - there is a folder called seeds, which makes it confusing... but as dparoli said, there is no **namespace**.  This is the right answer - remove the `use` stuff in your class as he says in the comments.

Comment: In which class I should write: `use Database\Seeds`?

Comment: You should NOT write `use Database\Seeds\{anythingclass}` in any class. If you have this `use` line please remove it, it is the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

I changed `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\ConnectRelationshipsSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

            $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ConnectRelationshipsSeeder::class);
            //$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

to

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Database\Seeds\PermissionsTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\ConnectRelationshipsSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

            $this->call('PermissionsTableSeeder');
            $this->call('RolesTableSeeder');
            $this->call('ConnectRelationshipsSeeder');
            //$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

This fixed my Error

```
php artisan db:seed
    Seeding: DefaultPermissionitemsTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultRoleItemsTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:view.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:create.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:edit.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:delete.users
Seeding: PermissionsTableSeeder

   ReflectionException  : Class Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder does not exist

  at D:\Work\Coding\Laravel\Epox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
    784|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
    785|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    786|         }
    787|
  > 788|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    789|
    790|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    791|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
    792|         // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.

  Exception trace:

  1   ReflectionClass::__construct("Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder")
      D:\Work\Coding\Laravel\Epox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788

  2   Illuminate\Container\Container::build("Database\Seeds\RolesTableSeeder")
      D:\Work\Coding\Laravel\Epox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:667

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

to

```
php artisan db:seed
    Seeding: DefaultPermissionitemsTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultRoleItemsTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:view.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:create.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:edit.users
Seeding: DefaultConnectRelationshipsSeeder - Role:Admin attached to Permission:delete.users
Seeding: PermissionsTableSeeder
Seeding: RolesTableSeeder
Seeding: ConnectRelationshipsSeeder
```

```
php artisan --version
    Laravel Framework 5.8.36
```